# ValueError: Tensor-typed variable initializers must either be wrapped in an init_scope or callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I keep on getting this error and don't seem to be able to solve it. The problem came up during upgrading keras to the new version which is integrated with tensorflow. Downgrading does solve this problem but I don't find that a long term solution. The following code I added is a recreation of the error using the keras Layers example. It was just used such that the error could be recreated without requiring anyone to download data sets or import more functions. For this reason if anyone can track the origin of the problem then other issues may follow which I can hopefully solve myself.
Hereby the code and Error:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras.utils import conv_utils
from keras import initializers
import numpy as np
import math

class SincConv1D(Layer):

    def __init__(self, N_filt, Filt_dim, fs, **kwargs):
        self.N_filt = N_filt
        self.Filt_dim = Filt_dim
        self.fs = fs

        super(SincConv1D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # The filters are trainable parameters.
        self.filt_b1 = self.add_weight(name='filt_b1', shape=(self.N_filt,), initializer='uniform',trainable=True)
        self.filt_band = self.add_weight(name='filt_band', shape=(self.N_filt,), initializer='uniform', trainable=True)

        # Mel Initialization of the filterbanks
        low_freq_mel = 80
        high_freq_mel = (2595 * np.log10(1 + (self.fs / 2) / 700))  # Convert Hz to Mel
        mel_points = np.linspace(low_freq_mel, high_freq_mel, self.N_filt)  # Equally spaced in Mel scale
        f_cos = (700 * (10 ** (mel_points / 2595) - 1))  # Convert Mel to Hz
        b1 = np.roll(f_cos, 1)
        b2 = np.roll(f_cos, -1)
        b1[0] = 30
        b2[-1] = (self.fs / 2) - 100
        self.freq_scale = self.fs * 1.0
        self.set_weights([b1 / self.freq_scale, (b2 - b1) / self.freq_scale])

        super(SincConv1D, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):


        # Get beginning and end frequencies of the filters.
        min_freq = 50.0
        min_band = 50.0
        filt_beg_freq = K.abs(self.filt_b1) + min_freq / self.freq_scale
        filt_end_freq = filt_beg_freq + (K.abs(self.filt_band) + min_band / self.freq_scale)

        # Filter window (hamming).
        n = np.linspace(0, self.Filt_dim, self.Filt_dim)
        window = 0.54 - 0.46 * K.cos(2 * math.pi * n / self.Filt_dim)
        window = K.cast(window, "float32")
        window = K.variable(window)


        # TODO what is this?
        t_right_linspace = np.linspace(1, (self.Filt_dim - 1) / 2, int((self.Filt_dim - 1) / 2))
        t_right = K.variable(t_right_linspace / self.fs)


        # Compute the filters.
        output_list = []
        for i in range(self.N_filt):
            # equation of convolution
            low_pass1 = 2 * filt_beg_freq[i] * sinc(filt_beg_freq[i] * self.freq_scale, t_right)
            low_pass2 = 2 * filt_end_freq[i] * sinc(filt_end_freq[i] * self.freq_scale, t_right)
            band_pass = (low_pass2 - low_pass1)
            band_pass = band_pass / K.max(band_pass)
            output_list.append(band_pass * window)
        filters = K.stack(output_list)  # (80, 251)
        filters = K.transpose(filters)  # (251, 80)
        filters = K.reshape(filters, (self.Filt_dim, 1,
                                      self.N_filt))  # (251,1,80) in TF: (filter_width, in_channels, out_channels) in PyTorch (out_channels, in_channels, filter_width)

        '''
        Given an input tensor of shape [batch, in_width, in_channels] if data_format is "NWC",
        or [batch, in_channels, in_width] if data_format is "NCW", and a filter / kernel tensor of shape [filter_width, in_channels, out_channels],
        this op reshapes the arguments to pass them to conv2d to perform the equivalent convolution operation.
        Internally, this op reshapes the input tensors and invokes tf.nn.conv2d. For example, if data_format does not start with "NC",
        a tensor of shape [batch, in_width, in_channels] is reshaped to [batch, 1, in_width, in_channels], and the filter is reshaped to
        [1, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]. The result is then reshaped back to [batch, out_width, out_channels]
        (where out_width is a function of the stride and padding as in conv2d) and returned to the caller.
        '''

        # Do the convolution.
        out = K.conv1d(x, kernel=filters)
        # out = K.reshape(out, shape=(None, 8618, 80,))
        return out

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        new_size = conv_utils.conv_output_length(input_shape[1], self.Filt_dim, padding="valid", stride=1, dilation=1)
        return (input_shape[0],) + (new_size,) + (self.N_filt,)

def sinc(band, t_right):
    y_right = K.sin(2 * math.pi * band * t_right) / (2 * math.pi * band * t_right)
    # y_left = flip(y_right, 0) TODO remove if useless
    y_left = K.reverse(y_right, 0)
    y = K.concatenate([y_left, K.variable(K.ones(1)), y_right])
    return y

class LayerNorm(layers.Layer):
    """ Layer Normalization in the style of https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06450 """

    def __init__(self, scale_initializer='ones', bias_initializer='zeros', **kwargs):
        super(LayerNorm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.epsilon = 1e-6
        self.scale_initializer = initializers.get(scale_initializer)
        self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.scale = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1],),
                                     initializer=self.scale_initializer,
                                     trainable=True,
                                     name='{}_scale'.format(self.name))
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1],),
                                    initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                                    trainable=True,
                                    name='{}_bias'.format(self.name))
        self.built = True

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        mean = K.mean(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        std = K.std(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        norm = (x - mean) * (1 / (std + self.epsilon))
        return norm * self.scale + self.bias

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

class Antirectifier(layers.Layer):
    '''This is the combination of a sample-wise
    L2 normalization with the concatenation of the
    positive part of the input with the negative part
    of the input. The result is a tensor of samples that are
    twice as large as the input samples.

    It can be used in place of a ReLU.

    # Input shape
        2D tensor of shape (samples, n)

    # Output shape
        2D tensor of shape (samples, 2*n)

    # Theoretical justification
        When applying ReLU, assuming that the distribution
        of the previous output is approximately centered around 0.,
        you are discarding half of your input. This is inefficient.

        Antirectifier allows to return all-positive outputs like ReLU,
        without discarding any data.

        Tests on MNIST show that Antirectifier allows to train networks
        with twice less parameters yet with comparable
        classification accuracy as an equivalent ReLU-based network.
    '''

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        shape = list(input_shape)
        assert len(shape) == 2  # only valid for 2D tensors
        shape[-1] *= 2
        return tuple(shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        inputs -= K.mean(inputs, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        inputs = K.l2_normalize(inputs, axis=1)
        pos = K.relu(inputs)
        neg = K.relu(-inputs)
        return K.concatenate([pos, neg], axis=1)

# global parameters
batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 40

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

# build the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(256, input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(LayerNorm())
model.add(SincConv1D(10, 10, 2000))
model.add(Antirectifier())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
model.add(layers.Dense(256))
model.add(Antirectifier())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes))
model.add(layers.Activation('softmax'))

# compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# train the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

# next, compare with an equivalent network
# with2x bigger Dense layers and ReLU

# next, compare with an equivalent network
# with2x bigger Dense layers and ReLU
```

The error obtained:

````
  File "C:\Users\Sebastiaan\anaconda3\envs\environment_01\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-9ba6ad267bc1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Sebastiaan/Documents/Aerospace engineering/thesis/deep_learning_stuff/pycharm_code/own_layers_error.py', wdir='C:/Users/Sebastiaan/Documents/Aerospace engineering/thesis/deep_learning_stuff/pycharm_code')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Sebastiaan/Documents/Aerospace engineering/thesis/deep_learning_stuff/pycharm_code/own_layers_error.py", line 191, in <module>
    model.add(SincConv1D(10, 10, 2000))
  File "C:\Users\Sebastiaan\anaconda3\envs\environment_01\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 182, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "C:\Users\Sebastiaan\anaconda3\envs\environment_01\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastiaan\anaconda3\envs\environment_01\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 489, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Sebastiaan/Documents/Aerospace engineering/thesis/deep_learning_stuff/pycharm_code/own_layers_error.py", line 54, in call
    window = K.variable(window)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastiaan\anaconda3\envs\environment_01\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 620, in variable
    value, dtype=dtype, name=name, constraint=constraint)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastiaan\anaconda3\envs\environment_01\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 814, in variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastiaan\anaconda3\envs\environment_01\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\variables.py", line 260, in __call__
    return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastiaan\anaconda3\envs\environment_01\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\variables.py", line 254, in _variable_v2_call
    shape=shape)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastiaan\anaconda3\envs\environment_01\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\variables.py", line 235, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kws: default_variable_creator_v2(None, **kws)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastiaan\anaconda3\envs\environment_01\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 2645, in default_variable_creator_v2
    shape=shape)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastiaan\anaconda3\envs\environment_01\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\variables.py", line 262, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastiaan\anaconda3\envs\environment_01\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 1411, in __init__
    distribute_strategy=distribute_strategy)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastiaan\anaconda3\envs\environment_01\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 1494, in _init_from_args
    raise ValueError("Tensor-typed variable initializers must either be "
ValueError: Tensor-typed variable initializers must either be wrapped in an init_scope or callable (e.g., `tf.Variable(lambda : tf.truncated_normal([10, 40]))`) when building functions. Please file a feature request if this restriction inconveniences you. ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Executing the following change solved the problem for me:

From:

```
window = K.variable(window)
```

To:

```
window = K.variable(lambda: window)
```